# Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears had left the flushing in her galled eyes

Tags: grammar, shakespeare

Here's from *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> within a month;
>
> Ere yet the salt of most unrighteous tears
>
> Had left the flushing in her galled eyes,
>
> She married:

I'm wondering about "Had left".
Is that the past perfect tense?
It seems strange if that is the case,
because she **had** married **before** the salt of her tears left the flushing.

Comment: I think this is typical Early Modern English where relationships between events are more clearly expressed in different tenses than would be the case now.

Comment: ' ... she married before the salt of her tears left the flushing.' Isn't that the point (if perhaps hyperbolically stated)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm asking about the grammar, not about the meaning(which is almost obvious).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I meant that it seems **grammatically** strange if "Had left" is the past perfect tense.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is a construction still used in today's English: 'He left before I had told him about the new car'. With 'He left after I had told him about the new car', there is no problem.

Comment: Except this is *before*, not *after*: "He left before I had told him about the new car" is slightly problematic in Modern English.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. The problem Quirk et al find with 'He left before I had told him about the new car' is that it is a paradoxical, not unacceptable, usage. See the quote below.

Comment: @Edwin Exactly; but the question is about Shakespeare, whose grammar is now 400 years old. I believe it wasn't unknown for an *irrealis* to use a more "concrete" tense, especially since we're talking poetry here, with a metre into which thoughts must be shoe-horned.

Comment: @Andrew: Per [this study](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/english-usage/projects/verb-phrase/book/bowiewallisaarts.pdf), use of past perfect has fallen over time. Maybe increasing numbers of otherwise "careful" speakers are looking for *justifiable* opportunities to avoid it (we're just going with the flow).

Comment: Well, you might wish to obtain a version of Hamlet that has a good glossary and/or notes on the language of the text. Or just read the play all the way through first, without worrying about catching the gist of every word or phrase or construction. Or choose something simpler to read.

Comment: @CarSmack  "Well, you might wish to obtain a version of Hamlet that has a good glossary and/or notes on the language of the text." As if I didn't have such a book.
Actually I checked at least three such books.

Comment: *Some comments deleted. Please try to keep comments relevant.* Given that you have done some research, it would be good to edit the question to say what that was and what its results were.

Comment: @Andrew Leach The question is about a usage, an example of which by Shakespeare is given. It is not 'about Shakespeare'. As OP says in a comment, " I'm asking about the grammar". And Quirk's Grammar is rather less than 400 years old.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There's no mention of the problem in all the annotated Hamlet books I have. Some of their authors are Harold Jenkins, G. R. Hibbard, Phillip Edwards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What I meant was "the question is about Shakespeare's English" which is not what is used now, and a book rather less than 400 years old is only going to address current usage, not what Shakespeare might have meant by his sentence. However, I stand by comment about shoe-horning language into metre; **that** can also produce odd results.

Comment: @Andrew Of course some of 'Shakespeare's English' is used now. And OP identifies this paradoxical usage of past perfect as being the point of his query. I'm not unfamiliar with expressions like the one Quirk [ACGEL; 1985] sanctions: 'I saw him before he had seen me'. Also(3. He left before I had arrived

 ... is the apparently paradoxical situation. Despite the past perfect, which suggests that the arrival took place before the leaving, before tells us that the leaving took place before the arrival.) jah; [UE](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/158654-before-they-had-gone-they-turned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is addressed in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language [Randolph Quirk et al. 1985, p 1020]:

> The use of the past perfective in before-constructions requires
>   special consideration.
>
> These four sentences seem to be equivalent in meaning:
>
> 11. I saw him before he saw me.
> 12. I had seen him before he saw me.
>
> **13. I saw him before he had seen me.**
>
> 14. I had seen him before he had seen me.
>
> Sentence 13 appears to be paradoxical in that the second in the
>   succession of events is marked with the past perfective, contrary to
>   what we have noted above in the after- and when-clauses. One
>   explanation is that the before-clause in 13, and perhaps also in 14,
>   may be nonfactual; that is to say, the event in the before-clause may
>   not have taken place ('He did not get a chance to see me, because I
>   evaded him').